# <video> tag renders differently in mobile and PC

Tags: html, css, web, html5-video

I'm working on a passion project of mine and seem to be facing this issue, the problem is I have a video tag to display a promo for the project and the video works when the user clicks play. The problem I face is how it renders in mobile and PC. In Desktop there's no issues as we can see the complete video with the pink background when the website loads up. But in mobile/iPad only the play button is visible but the video works on these devices, when the user clicks play but I don't find it visually appealing. I'm attaching pictures of the two below. Thanks for your answers in advance[image]!

[image: The first Image is Mobile and Second one is PC]

I'm also attaching my HTML code for the above section :

```
    <!--About Section-->
    <section class="about" id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 about-text">
                    <h1 class="about-h1">About</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 about-video">
                    <video width="650" controls>
                        <source src="./assets/img/Meko-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support HTML video.
                      </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Please read [ask], and how to post your code as a [mcve] before posting a question. When you're ready to post your code
⏩[look for the brackets `<>` button](https://i.ibb.co/935zWhk/mcve.jpg)⏪
[Images](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are OK but isn't mandatory but code as a [mcve] is required 99% of the time.

Comment: @zer00ne thanks for pointing this out. I have made the necessary changes. Thank you for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<p>Resize the browser window to see how the size of the video player will scale.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @Muhammet, thanks for the comment as per your advice, does it mean that I need to convert the file into an .ogg video? or this will this be done automatically? and also what's the significance behinf ogg format.

Comment: @JudeSavio you don't need .ogg format, all browsers are able to play .mp4 video and .mp3 audio.

Comment: no, you must include a responsive video

Answer (score 1):

### [Poster Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-poster)

Add the following attributes to `<video>` tag:

- `poster="`URL of an image`"`<sup>✥</sup>

Read this [article](https://css-tricks.com/what-does-playsinline-mean-in-web-video/) for details.

### Bootstrap 5 Classes

- `<`block level tag`>` (ex. `<div>` or `<figure>`) / parent element of `<video>`

  - `.ratio`
  - `.ratio-16bx9`

Refer to [Bootstrap 5 Ratio](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/ratio/)

<sup>✥</sup>If the poster doesn't show after page is loaded try the following:

- Add `autoplay` and `muted` attributes to the `<video>` tag.
- Add this code to either a `<script>` tag placed before the closing `</body>` tag or a JS file:

  ```js
  setTimeout(function() { document.querySelector('video').pause() }, 1000);
  ```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<section class="about" id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 about-text">
        <h1 class="h1">About</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 about-video">
        <figure class="ratio ratio-16x9">
          <video controls poster='https://i.ibb.co/1K4Ppr6/00.png' width='100%'>
        <source src="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs12s3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```